# How to make object bounce off edge of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a HTML/JavaScript game, but I need to make one of my objects bounce off the edge of the canvas instead of running off.

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.ca/3594744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Your object has an x & y position which is incremented/decremented each frame by the respective x or y velocity. Now all you need to do is detect when your object has collided with the bounds of the canvas, and negate the velocity in that respective direction to send the object in the opposite trajectory.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
// Called each frame to update the position of the object.
updatePosition():
  handleCollision()  
  updatePosition()

// Detects a collision with a wall, calculating the bounce offset, and new velocity if applicable.
handleCollision():
  // Detect collision with right wall.
  if (object.x + object.width > canvas.width)
    // Need to know how much we overshot the canvas width so we know how far to 'bounce'.
    overshootX = (object.x + object.width) - canvas.width
    object.x = canvas.width - overshootX - object.width
    velocityX = -velocityX

  // Repeat the same algorithm for top, left, and bottom walls.
```

Comment: I tried to do something like this, but it isn't working.  Here is the code   if (this.x + this.y > canvas.width){
         overshootX = (this.x + this.y) - canvas.width
    this.x = canvas.width - overshootX - this.y
    this.angle = -this.angle
    }